# What's the use of finally block in try with resources(Java 7)?

Tags: java, try-with-resources

The `finally` block is mainly used to prevent resource leaks which can be achieved in `close()` method of resource class. What's the use of finally block with `try-with-resources` statement, e.g:

```
class MultipleResources {

    class Lamb implements AutoCloseable {
        public void close() throws Exception {
            System.out.print("l");
        } 
    }

    class Goat implements AutoCloseable {
        public void close() throws Exception {
            System.out.print("g");
        } 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new MultipleResources().run();
    }

    public void run() throws Exception {
        try (Lamb l = new Lamb(); Goat g = new Goat();) {
            System.out.print("2");
        } finally {
            System.out.print("f");
        }
    }
}
```

Ref: K.Seirra, B. Bates OCPJP Book

Comment: to perform some operations regardless on execution result

Comment: Turn the question backwards: why it should be explicitly disabled for try-with-resources?

Answer (score 4):

Just like in regular `try-catch-finally` block - `finally` block is used when you want something to always happen, no matter if operation in `try` block succeeds or not.

I think your question is about providing some use-case when it is really useful. Try to imagine a situation when you have to tell one collabolator (or  publish an event) that your processing is finished - regardless of its result. You can then put in the `finally` block the code which is resposible for announcing the finishing of processing.

Plase note that when some operation in `try-with-resources` block without `catch` throws an exception, the code following that block will not be executed.

Answer (score 1):

The code in `finally` block with always get executed unless the thread that executing the code or the JVM is terminated.

This ensures that any resources you allocated will get cleaned up in the `finally` regardless.

The Java doc has a detail explanation of [finally](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html).

Comment: please note that code in `finally` block would not be executed if some JVM fail will happen - such as `OutOfMemoryError`

Comment: @MaciejDobrowolski, it can be executed even if `OutOfMemoryError` was thrown. Surely there are cases when `finally` block can be not executed. For example, if I shoot the bullet into my CPU when it executes the `try` block.

Comment: @TagirValeev that's right, I've just checked that. Neither `StackOverflowError` nor `OutOfMemoryError` will cause `finally` not to execute. The true JVM crash or `System.exit(0)` will. Thanks for pointing that out!